# How do I make tree rings over another shader in shader editor on tree stump model?

Tags: modeling, shaders

I'm trying to create rings on top inside my tree stump model using an art style from Puss in boots and the last wish, but I don't know how to give it that hand painted look or how to accurately place it within the center of my tree stump. The only reason I was able to make this shader was by following some YouTube videos. How do I get it right there without ruining the other shader?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=pA9d67AW" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/pA9d67AW/)

Comment: What should "that hand-painted look" look like? Something like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCOtt.jpg?

Comment: That looks very good but is there a way to "optionally" add cracks to make it look dry, old, or rotten?